# Why does Jupyter Notebook launch a blank command screen and then close when opening from Anaconda Navigator, Command Line, and Start Menu?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I try to open Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda Navigator or from the Anaconda Prompt or from the Start Menu shortcut, a new blank command screen opens up.  The command screen sits there for about 5 seconds with a blinking cursor not doing anything and then closes and goes away.  I am having trouble figuring out the next step because the command screen doesn't show an error or any text what so ever.  It just sits there blank and then goes away.

- Originally Jupyter Notebook working on computer but then all of a sudden one day it started doing this instead.  That day was about 5 months ago.
- I also have a desktop running the same software on the same operating system with the same antivirus and it is running both 3.7 and 3.9 versions of Jupyter Notebook just fine.  Never had this issue and is still fine.
- I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda multiple times thinking that it was somehow related to adding the PATH or installing it for all users and/or registering it.  I have tried all the combinations of those options and nothing seemed to work.
- I have even wiped the computer and reimaged to eliminate the chances of a registry key issue and then installed on a fresh system and still nothing.
- I also tried to go to the latest and greatest version of anaconda in addition to the 3.7 version that I was using.
- Also created a fresh environment where only Jupyter Notebook and requisites were installed.  Still the same result.

I am looking for some more direction in troubleshooting this.  Also, I am still fairly new to using anaconda and Jupyter notebook so it is completely possible I am missing something simple and easy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and arguing with corp IT, it turns on that the antivirus SEP was in fact terminating the program.  This is why the command screen would launch, be blank with no error codes, and then just close.  The SEP was terminating the program behind the scenes.  I had to look in the view logs, client management, control log to see where the record of the termination was being logged.  Some weeks of discussion and finally a screen recording as proof and they acknowledged the issue and added an exception.  Now all is well.

Looking back at my troubleshooting, I immediately went down the road of something was wrong with the path or the kernels or something else, but I should have first went to antivirus.  The biggest clue was that for a time early last year everything worked fine on the laptop.  Then suddenly this behavior started. At that instant an antivirus update/modification is more likely than the paths I was already headed down.